# How to send an automated email based on time from last successful jenkins build

Tags: email, jenkins, automation

I was wondering if there was a way of auto generating an email based on a time period since last successful build.

Eg: if there hasn't been a successful build in 1 month a email is sent?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) to query that job's last successful build time using the url

```
<JENKINS_URL>/job/<JOB_NAME>/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json?tree=timestamp
```

From there you can parse the json to get the timestamp, then use simple conditional logic in your automated script to send the email.